# Redis (jedis) cannot delete key with underscore

Tags: java, redis, jedis

someone encountered the problem of deleting an underscore key from Redis (using Jedis)?
example of key: "photo_on_verification_11111"
when i try to find and delete the key like in example it returns null (cannot find and delete this key),
but when i try to find and delete the key like "wink111" it works correctly

code of using method to delete:

```
    public void deleteValueByKey(String key){
        try(
            Jedis jedis = new Jedis("redisLocalhost"));
            ){
            jedis.del(key);
            log.info("The key {} is deleted", key);
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1) Are you sure the key exists? 2)do you get an exception?

Comment: 1) Yes, the key exists (I query it from redis-cli). 2) No, there is no exceptions. It just return null.  idk but i thing the problem with underscore key

Comment: another thing could be that you have misspelled the key.  Is there any extra space in the string that you store in redis?

Comment: is the key string already escaped? maybe there is a problem with special characters